# Change the initial rotation of an animation/channel (without removing its keyframes)

Tags: animation, bones

This is my animation and its initial rotation makes it point in this direction:

[image]

I want it to point towards this direction (but with the animation intact):

[image]

So I'll go to frame 0 and replace that rotation value:

[image]

Not surprisingly, the result is weird, because it skips directly from the keyframe I put there:

[image]

Is there a way to apply an initial rotation so that the animation starts on the rotation value I want it to have?

Comment: You can move the animation curves in the graph editor, just select the whole axis curve on which you want to adjust the rotation and drag it up or down.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Would you mind writing this is as an answer so I can put a nice green acceptance mark on it?